# PreparedStatement no comprueba si es Null Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que busque una matrícula en la base de datos, y que si no la encuentra ejecute una sentencia, y si ya existe la matricula que ejecute otra, pero siempre ( exista o no ) ejecuta la que dice no estar nula. He probado el siguiente código en el `ActionPerformed` del botón:

```
try {
            if(cn.BuscarMatricula(txt_Matricula.getText()).wasNull()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
                //cn.InsertarDatos(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString(), txt_Modelo.getText(), txt_Matricula.getText(), txt_NIF.getText(),reparacion);
            }else{
                cn.actualizarMatricula(reparacion, Integer.parseInt(txt_ID.getText()));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Actualizado correctamente");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GestionVehiculos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Y aquí adjunto el método de `actualizarMatricula`:

```
public void actualizarMatricula(boolean enReparacion, int id){
        Connection cn = Conectar();
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE vehiculos SET reparacion = ? WHERE id = ?");
            pst.setBoolean(1, enReparacion);
            pst.setInt(2, id);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
```

buscarMatricula:

```
public ResultSet BuscarMatricula(String matricula){
        Connection cn = Conectar();
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM vehiculos WHERE matricula = ?");
            pst.setString(1, matricula);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return rs;
    }
```

Algún motivo de porque siempre entra en el else, exista o no?
No consigo el error, y el log muestra que haga lo que haga intenta parsear el ID que está en el else.

Comment: Revisa primero que resultado esta devolviendo el método que usas para localizar la matricula, y luego revisa que tu condicional de comparación sepa diferenciar un elemento null y ademas de longitud cero.

Comment: @AndyC la mtricula está devolviendo lo que toca, la consulta funciona como debe, el problema está al comprobar si existe o no, quiero que si no existe ( devuelva null ) entre en el if y la cree

Comment: `actualizarMatricula` se ejecuta dentro del `else` así que no es relevante para saber porqué se evalúa la condición a `false`. Lo que se necesita es saber qué devuelve `BuscarMatricula`...

Comment: @SJuan76 pregunta actualizada con el método, devuelve la matricula, todo devolvía lo que le pedía, el problema ha venido cuando he querido comprobar si ya existía el registro

Comment: Revisa Optional<String>, es muy útil para elementos null, pero cuando agregues un dato usa Optional.ofNullable(String texto), eso permite recibir elementos nulo, luego los análisis posteriores ya quedaría de la lógica que quieres aplicar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando quiero resolver este tipo de situaciones esto es lo que hago y me funciona muy bien.

```
public boolean validarRegistro(String Codigo) throws Exception {
                this.Conexion();
                ResultSet rs;
                try {
                    String sql = "select count(*) as cantidad from Tabla where CodCampo = ?";
                    PreparedStatement ps = this.getCn().prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.setString(1, Codigo);
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    int cantidad = 0;
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        cantidad = rs.getInt("cantidad");
                    }
                    return cantidad == 0;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
```

Si el registro **no existe** te devolverá **true**, teniendo en cuenta esto hacemos lo siguiente.

```
try {

     if(validarRegistro(Codigo)){
          //Codigo que se ejecuta si NO EXISTE
     }else{
          //Codigo que se ejecuta si EXISTE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estoy editando mi respuesta. Si no quieres modificar nada en tu Dao (buscarMatricula), también podrías solo modificar una línea de tu front-end, así:

```
if(cn.BuscarMatricula(txt_Matricula.getText()).next()){
        //lo que haces si encuentras la matrícula
}else{
        //lo que haces si NO encuentras la matrícula
}
```

Estoy cambiando el wasNull() por el .next(), que es una práctica muy común al obtener tu ResultSet. Es una práctica común dentro del mismo Dao. De hecho se usa if(rs.next()) cuando el resultado que esperas solo es 1 registro (o ninguno) (que es tu caso); y while(rs.next()) cuando esperas varios registros

```
if(rs.next()){
    //y empiezo a obtener los datos de mi resultSet
    vehiculo.setNombreCampo(rs.getString("nombreCampo"));
}
```

Como puedes ver éste mismo if, ya lo estarías usando en tu front-End, en el Action-Performed

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Del [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()):

> Reports whether the last column read had a value of SQL NULL. Note that you must first call one of the getter methods on a column to try to read its value and then call the method wasNull to see if the value read was SQL NULL.

Es decir, siempre obtienes `false` porque no ha intentado leer la columna (lo cual tiene sentido si tienes en cuenta que podía haber muchas columnas en el mismo registro, algunas `null` y otra no, ¿cómo se decidiría entonces `wasNull`?)

En todo caso la estructura es mala; si solo quieres obtener un valor entonces `BuscarMatricula` debería devolverte ese valor, y no el `ResultSet` para que pierda con él (o ocultando así los detalles de implementación al código que llame al método)

Comment: Entonces como debería comprobar si el registro existe o no, no me ha quedado claro, porque devolviendo el valor tampoco podría comprobar si es un String vacío o no